# I am Using sublime text2. 'open in browser' is disabled for php files. Why?

Tags: php

I am developing locally.
I am not a novice web developer but I am new to sublime text.

I am following a video that uses Sublime text.
If I have an index.html file, I can right click and 'open in browser'.

This does not work with my index.php file.
If I 'Right click' this option is not there at all.

Can someone explain what to do please.
I believe there is a very simple way to do this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because php is a server processed language, so if you have no php server to process the file, you can't watch it.

Please consider [XAMP](https://www.apachefriends.org/de/index.html) for windows. With this Programm you can setup a PHP & MySQL Server on your local mashine.